# Como implementar e usar o método BinarySearch?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, busca-binária

Como implementar e usar o método `BinarySearch` de uma `List<T>`? Estou com dificuldade na implementação e também como usa-lo de forma pratica.

Segue o exemplo para ilustração:

```
int BuscaBinaria(List<string> lista, string parametro) 
{
   return (lista.BinarySearch(parametro));
}
```

Ele me retorna somente o índice de um elemento na lista caso exista na lista? Como poderia ser usado este método?

Comment: Segundo [a documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), se o elemento estiver na lista o seu índice será retornado; se não estiver, um número negativo será retornado (esse número codifica algumas informações adicionais, como a posição em que o elemento *estaria* na lista). Não entendi o que você quis dizer como "como implementar" (afinal o método já está implementado, é só usar).

Comment: Agora eu descobri com as respostas que ele não esta implementado de maneira correta era necessário ordenar a lista para usar o método :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, para usar esse método é necessário que a lista esteja **ordenada**. Isso é uma precondição para o algoritmo de busca binária, mas não custa relembrar...

Segundo, o método `BinarySearch` [com um único argumento](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) assume que a lista esteja ordenada segundo o critério de comparação "natural" dos seus elementos. Ou seja, é necessário tanto que esses elementos implementem a interface `IComparable` (ou sua variante genérica) quanto que a lista esteja ordenada segundo esse critério. No caso de listas de strings, a comparação é dada em ordem lexicográfica.

Se você precisar de mais controle sobre o critério de comparação, use [a variante que recebe um `IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ftfdbfx6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Lembrando sempre que a lista precisa estar ordenada *sob o mesmo critério*, para que a busca binária funcione corretamente.

O retorno do método é a posição que o elemento se encontra na lista, se ele estiver lá, ou um número negativo se ele não estiver. Note que se houver mais de uma ocorrência do elemento na lista, qualquer uma delas poderá ser retornada, não necessariamente a primeira (depende de quantos elementos tem a lista e quais as posições seu elemento ocupa).

Se o retorno for um número negativo, o elemento não está na lista. Se seu objetivo for apenas buscar, basta testar se o retorno é menor que zero. Mas se você quiser *inserir* esse elemento na lista caso ele já não esteja lá, o valor de retorno pode te ajudar a determinar onde essa inserção deve ocorrer: basta pegar o complemento bit a bit do valor de retorno:

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>() { "aoo", "bar", "baz" };

Console.WriteLine(lista.BinarySearch("bar")); // Está na lista (posição 1)

Console.WriteLine(lista.BinarySearch("bay")); // Não na lista (negativo)
Console.WriteLine(~lista.BinarySearch("bay")); // Se for inserir, insira na posição 2
```

[Exemplo no ideone](http://ideone.com/Uqiumg).

Answer (score 2):

Exatamente, ele faz uma busca nos valores e retorna o número do elemento na lista. Se não encontrar ele retornará um número negativo.

Note que só funciona se os valores da lista estiverem classificados, você tem que garantir isto por conta própria. Se não estiver classificada então qualquer resultado pode ser retornado e não será um correto, a não ser por pura coincidÊncia.

Se a lista não estiver classificada então a busca terá que ser feita de forma sequencial ([`Find()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Find_System_Predicate__0__), por exemplo), o que é quase garantido que será mais lento, possivelmente absurdamente mais lento em grandes listas.

Pode garantir que a lista está classificada? Duvido, isso é altamente incomum e se estiver é porque classificou antes, o que será muito ineficiente.

Se quiser que a estrutura seja garantidamente classificada tem que usar outra. Por exemplo, a [`SortedList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) ou a [`SortedDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Nelas uma busca por valores funciona como busca binária.

Obviamente este método nesta forma neste código acrescenta pouco. É claro que ele pode ter uma propósito de criar uma abstração, se isto for feito de forma consciente, ok.